# ¿Cual es el typeof de 0?

Tags: javascript, array

estoy haciendo una funcion que extrae todos los numeros de un array y los almacena en otro, pero cuando llego al 0 no lo reconoce como numero, aqui mi codigo:

```
function filter_list(l) {
  return l.filter(function(e){
     if(typeof e == "number") return e;
  });

}
```

Array pasado como parametro: [1,'a','b',0,15]
Array devuelto: [1,15], pero deberia ser: [1, 0, 15]

Gracias y un saludo.

Comment: Es de tipo `number`, tu problema esta por otro lado

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Estas realizando mal el filter.

La función filter retorna un booleano y dependiendo del valor retornado toma o quita el elemento del array.
cuando retornas un `0` es igual a retornar `false` o `null`, como es en los otros casos donde no retornas un valor.

El correcto uso del seria:

```js
function filter_list(l) {
  return l.filter(function(e){
     return typeof e == "number";
  });
}

console.log(
  filter_list([1,'a','b',0,15])
);
```

Quitando la clausula  `if` y retornando el booleano directamente.

Comment: Muchas gracias, estaba entendiendo mal la función filter, ahora si me quedó claro.